# Evaluate string on record table,

Tags: vb.net

How to evaluate match on the record table with vb I have a code like this

```
Dim absenperintah As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from mytable where kodetp ='109'", cekdata)

            absenperintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cekdata.Open()
            Dim valuex = "500"
            Using cekbaca As SqlDataReader = 
            absenperintah.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                If cekbaca.Read = True Then
                    Dim nilxbaca = cekbaca("rumus_k") --> record in the table is   1906650*(3.7/100) 
                    Dim nilmy = valuex + nilxbaca
                    Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(nilmy, Nothing)
                    MsgBox(result)
                End If
                cekbaca.Close()
            End Using
            cekdata.Close()
```

I get the result 185,070,546 it should be result =70,564.55

how to get result =70,564.55  from `Dim nilHy = valuex + nilxbaca`

Comment: Have you tested the same query in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring these numbers as strings and they are being calculated accordingly.

What you think you are doing:

```
500 + 1906650*(3.7/100) = 70,564.55
```

If you were processing these as numbers, it would perform math and your calculation would work.

However, you have declared these values as strings. Therefore the code is actually running like this:

```
"500" + "1906650*(3.7/100)" 'String concatenation. Not math.
5001906650*(3.7/100) = 185,070,546
```

Try this code instead:

```
Dim absenperintah As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from mytable where kodetp ='109'", cekdata)

absenperintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cekdata.Open()
Dim valuex = "500" 
Using cekbaca As SqlDataReader = 
      absenperintah.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    If cekbaca.Read = True Then
        Dim nilxbaca = cekbaca("rumus_k") 'record in the table is   "1906650*(3.7/100)" 
        Dim nilmy = valuex & " + " & nilxbaca 'makes "500 + 1906650*(3.7/100)"
        'Note: your next line of code, DataTable.Compute() will evaluate a 
        ' (string) formula over several rows. 
        Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(nilmy, Nothing)
        'Based on this code here, you are only processing one row. 
        'Maybe .Compute() is totally unnecessary here.  
        'You would be better to say: result = 500 + nilxbaca
        ' or maybe declare valuex as integer, to help the compiler treat it like a number instead of a string.
        ' or maybe your original code did apply this formula over several rows.
        ' ... In that case, my example would fix your Compute() formula.

        MsgBox(result)
    End If
    cekbaca.Close()
End Using
cekdata.Close()
```